# Why the heat transfer through the walls of a room is modelled as a 1D?

Tags: thermodynamics, models, heat-conduction

*The heat transfer through a medium can be assumed to be one dimensional if the heat transfer happens predominantly along just one principal axis of the coordinate system.*

If the heat transfer through the wall of a room can be assumed 1D, then this should imply the heat transfer along the other two directions is relatively small.

My question is how did we come to that conclusion that heat transfer in other two directions is small?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how did we come to that conclusion that heat transfer
> in other two directions is small?

Because it is assumed that there are no temperature gradients in the other two directions, i.e., the other two directions are isotherms.

> Going a step further, how did we conclude that temperature gradients
> in the other two directions are negligible?

The 1D heat transfer assumes steady state conditions with constant temperatures maintained on each side of a wall with surface dimensions much greater than of the thickness of the wall.

The electrical analogy is a parallel plate capacitor where the dimensions of the plates are much greater than the plate separation.  The voltage between the plates is analogous to the temperature difference and the voltage gradient (electric field) between the plates is analogous to the temperature gradient. The voltage gradient is in one direction between the plates as is the temperature gradient in the wall. In each case we neglect so called "edge effects" (the edges of the wall or plates).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Going a step further, how did we conclude that temperature gradients in the other two directions are negligible?

Comment: That’s because the wall reaches thermal equilibrium faster than wall-air interface.

Comment: @HarshitRajput "how did we conclude that temperature gradients in the other two directions are negligible" By measuring them. You don't need any fancy apparatus. Just walk around a room and feel the temperature at different places!

Comment: @HarshitRajput I have updated my answer to respond to your follow up question.

Comment: I'm Convinced, Thank You everyone.

Comment: @HarshitRajout so was my answer acceptable to you?